# How do i stop my SQL search at a specific record?

Tags: sql

I have a search

```
select product_code,data_code 
from prod_text 
where (product_code like 'all%' and data_code like 'ABCDE')
order by Data_Code
```

This outputs my ABCDE code in order from the database (not numerical/text order) but I would also like to stop the search once a specific 'data_code' is reached then move on to the next product?

```
1 4 2 3 6 5 gives output 1 4 2 3

3 2 6 5 4 1 gives output 3 2
```

if I choose 6 as my 'stop' data_code

Any solutions very welcome

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Please add the tag for your DBMS (postgresql, oracle, sql-server, ...)

Comment: What defines your order? i.e. Why is it `1, 4, 2, 3, 6, 5' and not `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6`, or `6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're ordering by the data_code, so would something like this would work for you?

```
select product_code,data_code 
from prod_text 
where (product_code like 'all%' and data_code like 'ABCDE')
  and data_code < @stop
order by Data_Code
```

If you want to stop only if you actually find your 'stop' data_code, you could solve it using a subquery.